# ASP.NET Core Error Development Mode only in Area

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, github, asp.net-core

In Azure, I have a small app deployed: https://jsnamespace.azurewebsites.net/.
In localhost, it works perfectly when navigating to localhost/Admin.
However, in the deployed app, navigating to https://jsnamespace.azurewebsites.net/Admin yields an error:

---

Error.
An error occurred while processing your request.
Request ID: 0HLLGMN77UU3U:00000001

Development Mode
Swapping to Development environment will display more detailed information about the error that occurred.

Development environment should not be enabled in deployed applications, as it can result in sensitive information from exceptions being displayed to end users. For local debugging, development environment can be enabled by setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development, and restarting the application.

---

The source code is available publicly on GitHub:
https://github.com/cdaley78/JsNamespace

I have seen other suggestions for issues like these setting ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT in Azure. I feel this should not be necessary considering everything works except the code located in the Area.

What am I missing?

I have tried in Azure setting ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to "Development" in the Web App –> "Applications Settings." That makes no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you set the **`ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development`** (and then **restart** the App Service), you'll find out it complains that there's no related View files found:

[image]

This error happens because you're setting the `Admin/Home/Index.cshtml` in [the wrong way](https://github.com/cdaley78/JsNamespace/blob/673cbe670285ba380af4c1dcbfe0ec717fad9fa1/JsNamespace/JsNamespace.csproj#L9-L12) :

```
    <Compile Remove="Areas\**" />
    <Content Remove="Areas\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="Areas\**" />
    <None Remove="Areas\**" />

    ...

    <Compile Include="Areas\Admin\Controllers\HomeController.cs" />

    ...

    <None Include="Areas\Admin\Views\Home\Index.cshtml" />
```

2. To fix that issue, remove those unnecessary configurations around `Areas/Admin` as below:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- <Compile Remove="Areas\**" />
    <Content Remove="Areas\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="Areas\**" />
    <None Remove="Areas\**" /> -->
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="bundleconfig.json" />
    <Content Remove="compilerconfig.json" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <_ContentIncludedByDefault Remove="compilerconfig.json" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- <Compile Include="Areas\Admin\Controllers\HomeController.cs" /> -->
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- <None Include="Areas\Admin\Views\Home\Index.cshtml" /> -->
    <None Include="bundleconfig.json" />
    <None Include="compilerconfig.json" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.1.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy" Version="2.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="2.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.1.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Areas\Admin\Data\" />
    <Folder Include="Areas\Admin\Models\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

3. Now it works fine for me :

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. I am not sure how the noise in the project file was introduced. It is too bad the project made its way to deployment to expose the issue. I wonder how I could have seen this in localhost. Thanks again.

Comment: @cdaley78 Hi, I haven't figure out what magic is spelled by VisualStudio itself when I run `Debug` button. I often use `VSCode` to develop a .NET Core App. But as a walkaround, if I run it with a local `IIS Express` manually, it throws too.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that you are not using **AddEnvironmentVariables**. In your `startup.cs` you should do similar to this

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It turns out there was noise in my project file. I am not sure how it got there. But, removing the junk solved the problem. Thank you for answering!